# Spring Autowire not initialized with KotlinTest 3.1.8

Tags: spring, kotlin, kotlintest

I know this should be possible, as others have reported it working.  However, in a simple 'demo' project (Spring Initializer), I can't get the autowired property to be initialized within the test.

When I execute the test in "JpaTestApplicationTests", I can't get past receiving "lateinit property repo has not been initialized
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException".

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Below is my application file, bean to be autowired, and test:

Application:

```
package com.example.jpaTest

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class JpaTestApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(JpaTestApplication::class.java, *args)
}
```

Bean:

```
package com.example.jpaTest

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository

@Repository
interface FakeRepository : CrudRepository<Fake, String>
```

Test:

```
package com.example.jpaTest

import io.kotlintest.*
import io.kotlintest.specs.*
import io.kotlintest.spring.SpringListener
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration

@ContextConfiguration(classes = [JpaTestApplication::class])
class JpaTestApplicationTests : StringSpec() {
    override fun listeners() = listOf(SpringListener)

    @Autowired
    lateinit var repo: FakeRepository

    init {
        "can get by id"{
            val it = Fake("Blah","testName1")
            val saved = repo.save(it)

            repo.findOne(saved.uuid) shouldBe saved
        }
    }
}
```

Relevant Gradle entries:

```
  buildscript {
    ext {
      kotlinVersion = '1.2.61'
      springBootVersion = '1.5.16.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
      mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
      classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
      classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
      classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}")
      classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:$kotlinVersion"
    }
  }

  apply plugin: 'kotlin'
  apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
  apply plugin: "kotlin-jpa"
  apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

  test {
      useJUnitPlatform()
  }

  dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin')
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")

      testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile 'io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:3.1.8'
      testCompile 'io.kotlintest:kotlintest-extensions-spring:3.1.8'
  }
```

Comment: did you manage to solve this?